# School Wifi Speed is good but it takes extremely long to make a connection to webpage

Tags: networking, internet, dns, vpn

When I connect to on-campus WiFi, it take about 30 seconds to load a page; however, there is some odd behaviour. For example, It take 30 seconds to load Facebook, but once I have Facebook loaded, navigation on that Web site is fast. I get the same behaviour with Google and other Web sites.

When I run the [Ookla Speed Test](https://www.speedtest.net/), it said "Finding Optimal Server" for about 30 seconds, but once connected, the speed test was normal.

One interesting note is that when I connect to the schools VPN, while on the campus (redundant), the WiFi works fine.

My school's IT team essentially told me to eat bricks because I'm using a Linux machine (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS).

Could this have something to do with my DNS?

Comment: The speed increase is almost certainly due to image caching. You *could* try turning off image autoloading, I suppose

Comment: Ok, but from my understanding that wouldn't help with the initial problem of pages taking 30 seconds to load up?

Comment: I'm thinking the initial delay is because of image loading. Turn if off, and you'll see ugly-but-fast versions of those pages (maybe).

Comment: An important question here is: Are you sure the behavior you complain of is *fundamentally* different/worse than in different devices with different OSes? If not fundamentally different then there there's nothing to "fix" regarding the OS, obviously.

Comment: 100% My iphone work fine. Just my linux computer.

Comment: I'd be curious as to your DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up fixing it bc my DNS setting were messed up. When I connected the wifi, it was not adding my schools ip to the resolv.conf. But when i connected to the vpn it does.

I had a customized configuration of my DNS, the 8.8.8.8 one. Confirming with my schools IT team, they don't allow customized configurations on their network

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).